# Check if the next value extracted by >> is going to be a string or int

Tags: c++, if-statement, file-io, conditional-statements

This seems like it should be ridiculously simple, but I can't figure it out.  So I'm reading in values from a file, and I need to know if the next input from that file is going to be a string or an int.  Something along the lines of:

```
if(next command from file is an int){ do this; }
else{ do this; }
```

here's the code I have so far:

```
while (!(myFile.eof())) {

    char inPeek = myFile.peek();
    int input;
    string command;

    if (isdigit(inPeek)) {
        int input;
        myFile >> input;

        if (command == "push") {
            MyStack.push(input);
            cout << "Pushed " << input << endl;
        }
        else {
            MyQueue.append(input);
            cout << "Appended " << input << endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        myFile >> command;

        if (command == "pop") {
            MyStack.pop();
            cout << "Popped" << endl;
        }
        if (command == "serve") {
            MyQueue.serve();
            cout << "Served" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

But `if(isdigit(inPeek))` never returns true. The file that I'm reading from looks like this essentially like this:

```
append 10
serve
append 20
append 30
serve
push 10
push 50
push 20
push 20
pop
```

Comment: Why can't you read the command and then check inside your program whether your commands need some other input or not ? Something like : `if (command == "push") read_input_and_process (); else if (command == "pop" ) don't_read_input_and_process ();`

Comment: I think PRP has the right idea. Another way to do this is with C++11's `auto` specifier, but honestly, would be a bit messy.

Comment: Also `if(isdigit(inPeek)) never returns true` this may be because of the space after each command that is still in the buffer. To quickly check this do a comparison `if inPeek == space` and find out.

Comment: Don't use `while (!(myFile.eof()))`. Instead read until reading fails.

Comment: @eziegl `auto` is no use here, it must be deduced at compile-time

Comment: Thanks guys! Sorry I figured it out and forgot to let y'all know. I just read in the command like PRP said to, worked great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. There's no a way to know the type of a stream of bytes.

The input is read as a stream of bytes and that stream could be interpreted as a number, a character or a string (or whatever you want).

As PRP said, you should read the input as a string and check inside your program whether your commands need some other input or not.

Also, the function 'isdigit' will return true when the byte read is between 0 and 9.